# How can i solve this Problem to build my App with Pods?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.x

I try to build my App with Pods but it doesn´t work. I already set the variables PODS_ROOT and PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH also id dit run 'pod install' but it still doesn´t work. Always getting this error below

[image]

do anyone have a solution for this problem? i tried many methods.

Comment: Did you run `pod install`? And if so, did it produce any errors?

Comment: Oh an did you open your project or the workspace created by `pod`?

Comment: i did run pod install many times :/ my project was closed

Comment: Did you tried to delete all ??

Comment: yes i did delete all

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the pod configuration is modified outside the pod installation (for example, cloning a repository and running it in a different machine, without a clean `pod install`)

Try the following solution:

1 - In your project folder, delete the `Podfile.lock` file

2 - On the terminal, in your project folder, run the command: `pod deintegrate --verbose`

3 - On the terminal, in your project folder, run the command: `pod install --verbose`